# How to make two treeviews to expand and collapse together

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, treeview

I want to have two treeviews, that are binded to the same **Data** 
and different only in the headers that they present for each item (binded to a different string property inside the data).

I would like that when a treeItem is expanded in one tree, the twin node would be expanded as well in the other tree,  and the same for collapsing.

I thought about adding a property in the Data that would represent "IsExpanded" property of the tree and to bind the Expander button to it, and in this way it would affect both trees, I just don't have ideas how to implement it, since i'm quite new to WPF.

Thanks in advance for any kind of help.
Code after nit's answer:

```
<Window x:Class="MyApp.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:model="clr-namespace:MyApp.Model"
    xmlns:viewModel="clr-namespace:MyApp.ViewModels"
    xmlns:views="clr-namespace:MyApp.Views"
    xmlns:converters="clr-namespace:MyApp.Converters"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Window.Resources>
    <converters:EnumToPicConverter x:Key="Converter"></converters:EnumToPicConverter>
    <!--Control colors.-->
    <Style x:Key="MyTreeViewItemStyle" TargetType="TreeViewItem">
        <Setter Property="IsExpanded" Value="{Binding Path=IsExpanded}" />
    </Style>
    <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type model:TreeNode}" ItemsSource="{Binding ChildListNodes}">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Image Source="{Binding Path=EntityType,Converter={StaticResource Converter}}" />
            <TextBlock Margin="5,0" Text="{Binding Name1}" />
        </StackPanel>
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
<Window.DataContext>
    <viewModel:TreeViewModel/>
</Window.DataContext>
<DockPanel>
    <Grid DockPanel.Dock="Top" Name="LoadRow">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <views:DbChooser Path="{Binding Path1}" ReloadCommand="{Binding LoadFileACommand}"  Grid.Column="0"/>
        <views:DbChooser Path="{Binding Path2}" ReloadCommand="{Binding LoadFileBCommand}"  Grid.Column="1"/>
    </Grid>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"></ColumnDefinition>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <TreeView Name="LeftTree" ItemsSource="{Binding RootNode}" ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource MyTreeViewItemStyle}" Grid.Column="0" />
   <TreeView Name="RightTree" ItemsSource="{Binding RootNode}" ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource MyTreeViewItemStyle}" Grid.Column="1" />
    </Grid>
</DockPanel>
```

Code that I have added in the TreeNode C#:

```
        public bool IsExpanded
    {
        get { return _isExpanded; }
        set
        {
            _isExpanded = value;
            RaisePropertyChangedEvent("IsExpanded");
        }
    }
```

Comment: an "IsExpanded" property is where my brain went... How are the trees accessing the data currently?

Comment: Maybe I explained myself not that good.
The trees are binded to a view model that holds a Root, they are just both binded to the same root...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add property `IsExpanded` in your `Data` class and set `ItemContainerStyle` for `TreeViews` as below.
Need not to say Data class must implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` and raise property change notification for `IsExpanded` and other properties

```
<Window.Resources>
     <Style x:Key="MyTreeViewItemStyle" TargetType="TreeViewItem">
           <Setter Property="IsExpanded" Value="{Binding IsExpanded, Mode=TwoWay}" />
     </Style>
     <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type model:TreeNode}" ItemsSource="{Binding ChildListNodes}">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Image Source="{Binding Path=EntityType,Converter={StaticResource Converter}}" />
                <TextBlock Margin="5,0" Text="{Binding Name1}" />
            </StackPanel>
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate >
    </Window.Resources>
<TreeView x:Name="Tree1" ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource MyTreeViewItemStyle}"/>
<TreeView x:Name="Tree2" ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource MyTreeViewItemStyle}"/>
```

Comment: The problem that I have, is that the ViewModel holds a property which is the Root Node, But the Class that describes that TreeNode, is in my Model part, so now I encounter a problem:
1. If I leave it in the model, I cannot bind the view to this property.
2.If I make it in the ViewModel, I need to change datacontext(I think..) to be the one of the TreeNode class, but now I loose the ItemsSource property (meaning the RootNode of the tree..)

What do I miss here or where am I wrong? @nit

Comment: no.. you implement this property on model and bind it as shown in my answer.. it will applied fine..try it

Comment: Thanks for your patience.
That's what I did but it tells me "Cannot resolve property 'IsExpanded' in data context of type "MyApp.TreeViewModel"
which is the data context of the rest of the window...

Comment: I added the whole XAML code of the window, you will notice I added what you told me and this is where I see the error I mentioned in the comment above

Comment: and rootnode is collection of models?

Comment: Yes, root node is defined like this:
public CustomObservableCollection<TreeNode> RootNode

Comment: one more question.. childlistnodes are also of type TreeNode?

Comment: excatly, in the TreeNode class (which is in the model) there is
public ObservableCollection<TreeNode> ChildListNodes

Comment: great.. first of all update your datatemplate to the heirarchicaldatatemplate as shown in my updated answer.. and in TreeNode class add IsExpanded property..compile..it will work

Comment: Again, Thank you SO much @nit for your patience. but it still doesn't work. my XML is changed as you said.
and I added the IsExpanded property inside "TreeNode" (pasted code in the original question). it still doesn't bind the two trees to work together, and it stlil shows "cannot resolve property 'IsExpanded' .... "

Comment: it is very strange as it should work.. can you check if the setter of IsExpanded is called when you expand collapse treeview item... here is the sample code of what you want to achieve http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/treeview-control/handling-selection-expansion-state/

Comment: I have seen this link but when I tried to imitate the idea I failed..
The setter is **not** called but the getter is called.. what can cause this?

Comment: this is really strange... and isexpanded getter is being called for all the items? i dont have my visual studio with me right now.. will check this and let you know

Comment: Yes, the getter works for all the items.. and the setter is never called.
My feelings is like, who should call the getter, i mean after I press "+" to expand, it calls the getter, but who should call the setter of it, not sure I quite got it.. 

Thank you for your help again..

Comment: I was trying this earlier on my own -- my own classes/xaml/etc... It was definitely using the IsExpanded property that I created (i.e. when I instantiated as true, they were all open by default)... It did not appear to hit the setter when I opened/closed while it ran. @nit your code is working for you?

Comment: @matansab, bdimag Guys, it works, just need to set the binding to twoway (updated the answer) 'Value="{Binding IsExpanded, Mode=TwoWay}" />'. Strange that is not twoway by default. Tested it, worked well

Comment: Thank you so much! It works.
I really appreciate it!

Comment: it drank too much of blood.. had to resolve it.. \m/